# code c++ to add prefix keyword to be valid

Tags: c++

I made this code but I need to add it
the password must contains keyword(yat) as prefix to be valid 
hint :- program should be comprtible with any number .
can anyone do that?

```
enum PWSIZE //Array Size

{

    PASSWORD_SIZE = 20


};


//Function Prototype

int testNum(char []);

int re_enter(char []);


int main()

{

    char password[PASSWORD_SIZE]; //To hold password

    int length;

    length = strlen(password);
    while(1)
    {
        //Get the password.
        do{
            cout<< "Please enter a password with at least 8 characters.\n";
            cout << "Enter your password: ";
            cin.getline(password, PASSWORD_SIZE);
            length = strlen(password);
        }while(length < 8);

        //Call function.
        if(testNum(password))
            continue;           //if return 1 pass below
        if(re_enter(password))
            continue;

        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int testNum(char pswd[])
{

    int count;

    bool upper_flag = 0, lower_flag = 0, digit_flag = 0;

    for (count = 0; count<strlen(pswd); count++)    //don't need to Size use strlen
    {

        if (isupper(pswd[count]))
            upper_flag = 1;
        else if (islower(pswd[count]))
            lower_flag = 1;
        else if (isdigit(pswd[count]))
            digit_flag = 1;
    }
    if(!upper_flag)
    {
        cout << "The password does not contain an uppercase letter.\n";
    }

    if(!lower_flag)
    {
        cout << "The password does not contain a lowercase letter.\n";
    }
    if(!digit_flag)
    {
        cout << "The password does not contain a digit.\n";
    }
    if(upper_flag && lower_flag && digit_flag)
        return 0;   //if all pass
    else
        return 1;
}

int re_enter(char  passwd[])

{

    char compare_password[PASSWORD_SIZE] = {0,};

    cout << "Re Enter Your password" <<endl;

    cin.getline(compare_password, PASSWORD_SIZE);

    if(strcmp(passwd, compare_password))

    {

        cout << "Password Not Match" << endl;

        return 1;

    }

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Ignoring your question - you should take a more serious look at this `char password[PASSWORD_SIZE]; int length; length = strlen(password);` as it's just not safe.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text.  The `std::string` will dynamically expand as necessary; an array is a fixed size and can suffer from buffer overrun.

Comment: You should use the new data type called `bool`, to represent `true` and `false` values.  Using an integer, 1 and 0, is so archaic (like around the 1960's, before C or C++ were invented).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the prefix:

```
bool is_valid_password(const std::string& password)
{
  static const std::string expected_prefix = "yat";
  const std::string prefix = password.substr(0, expected_prefix.length());
  return prefix == expected_prefix;
}
```

Another alternative is to use `std::string::find`:

```
return password.find(expected_prefix) == 0;
```

If you *must* use character arrays (C-Style strings), look up the [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) function:

```
bool is_valid(char const * password)
{
  return strstr(password, "yat") == password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if  (memcmp ("yat", password, 3) == 0)...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19416747)

Comment: Fair point - it simply tests the first 3 characters of the password to be "yat". Like strcmp but limited to a given number of characters.